# Is there a way to create variables in php based on what is returned by an sql query?

Tags: php

I created a query that retrieves from a database a users street address, their state, and their city. Now I'm trying to put all of this info into a single $var but my code doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. I'm new to PHP so I apologize for any mistakes I've made.

```
require 'config.php';
$host ="myhost";
$user ="username";
$pass ="mypassword";
$db="mydb";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ( $mysqli->connect_errno ) {
    echo $mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$sql = "SELECT  addresses.street_address AS street_address, addresses.state AS state, addresses.City AS city
            FROM users
        LEFT JOIN addresses
            ON users.address_id=addresses.address_id
        WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."';";
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);
if(!$results) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    exit();
}
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();

var_dump($row['state']);
var_dump($row['city']);
var_dump($row['street_address']);

var $address= $row['street_address']. $row['city']. $row['state'];
```

Comment: PHP doesn't use the `var` keyword. Just write `$address = ...`

Comment: You seem to know that, since you didn't use it for any of the other variables.

Comment: you should of got an error message, if you didn't you should make sure your displaying those, it will make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$street = $row['street_address'];
 $city = $row['city'];
$state =  $row['state'];

$address = $street  .  '  '  .  $city .  '  '  .  $state;

echo $address;
```

Comment: no need to create extra variables, just wastes memory, CP cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list() language construct. PHP 5.6 will start with the right most parameter, but 7.* will start with the left most as the manual says https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php.

PHP 5.6

```
list($city, $state, $streetAddress) = $rows;
$address = "$streetAddress | $city | $state";
```

PHP 7.*

```
list($streetAddress, $city, $state) = $rows;
$address = "$streetAddress | $city | $state";

// or

[$streetAddress, $city, $state] = $rows;
$address = "$streetAddress | $city | $state";
```

Comment: "Since mysqli extension is removed in 7.0" completely false

Comment: You are right. Its the mysql extension https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php. I always used PDO.